# How to isolate memory leak of .NET application running on mono on docker in Mesos

Tags: .net, docker, mono, owin, mesos

We are having a problem where a .NET application (Web Api on OWIN host) is leaking memory and we don't know how to identify the source of the leak. My instinct is to take memory dumps over time and work out which objects are hanging around. I just don't know how to do that especially in a production environment. I'm guessing we need to change the app to run with the profiler, and have it write its output to a file that isn't on the docker image so we can pull it down and analyse locally. Any guidance on how to achieve this would be appreciated.

Comment: maybe a stupid question, but have you tried ti reproduce memory leak on your dev machine?

Comment: How do you know it's a memory leak? Can you provide some logs/dumps/metrics?